# How to apply filter on join table in many-to-many relation

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js, objection.js

I have many-to-many relationships between class and adventures.

So, I have 3 tables named **class**, **adventure** and **class_has_adventure**.

Class Table:

[image]

Adventure Table:

[image]

class_has_adventure Table:

[image]

as you can see in the **class_has_adventure** table I have 2 additional fields named **date_start** and **date_stop**. I want to add a filter on **date_start** and **date-stop** in the join table (class_has_adventure).
I am using **Knex** and **Objection** in my Nodejs app. I tried some methods but I didn't get results. I have used **withGraphJoined**, **withGraphFetch** and **joinRelation**.

Is there any way to add the filter on the join table (class_has_adventure) while querying the data from **adventure** or **class**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use Knex [`join`](https://knexjs.org/guide/query-builder.html#join), in your case:

```
await knex.select('*')
        .from('class')
        .join('class_has_adventure', 'class.id', 'class_has_adventure.id_class')
        .where('class_has_adventure.date_start', '>', new Date('2023-02-10'))
```